# Azure mobile service for Android Google Cloud message(GCM) never sents notification to device

Tags: android, azure, google-cloud-messaging, azure-mobile-services

xamarian Android project not always receives the push message triggered from push.gcm.send(). Broadcast receiver calls only onregister() first time, but not calls onmessage(). **my php server script works well with  https://android.googleapis.com**, and it calls onmessage() of broadcast reciver. Also Native android project with azure mobile service use push sharp client behaves same, it doesn't call onmessage() when push.gcm.send() executed in azure server. let me know what iam doing wrong, i use the perfect Applicationkey,server key,project number,........Below is the log details.I am getting status code 201.

**Log entry details:**

INFORMATION

Test Push notification sent: APA91bELUme4gM35eHBH4dmxo7AVBkmVu6Gsown_8zrROb5SsKzHn7MgpypBirmmDDuyPlr8hRjBDRX2lBc_j9voAPYv2RotXiVTHMaXFRRADu0xNfrPk-g-bCkfsCO7Uv-OnPMW8bgmTHIX8u8exKpGxfSrFZvN8dEDAoC5iw { isSuccessful: true,
statusCode: 201,
body: '',
headers: 
{ 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
'content-type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8',
server: 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
date: 'Tue, 27 May 2014 19:40:00 GMT' },
md5: undefined }

**Input Script:**

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    request.execute({
        success: function() {
            // Write to the response and then send the notification in the background
            request.respond();
            push.gcm.send(item.channel, item.text, {
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log('Push notification sent: ', response);
                }, error: function(error) {
                    console.log('Error sending push notification: ', error);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please double-check your test is correct by ensuring your client code matches the completed example with appropriate fields replaced from here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=331303&clcid=0x409

The full instructions are found at: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-mobile-services-android-get-started-push/

If you still encounter issues after double-checking these, send me email at toddreif@microsoft.com with your Mobile Service account name.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Migrate a Mobile Service to use Notification Hubs.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn635173.aspx)

Microsoft had been upgraded the Mobile Service, to push notifications powered by Notification Hubs. You will not be affected if you created the mobile service before the upgrade.

Base on the response { isSuccessful: true, statusCode: 201, body ... }, it indicate that your Mobile Service is the new version.

If you prefer to send push **without** Notification Hubs, **don't** use push.gcm.send, use the following code snippet instead.

```js
var legacyGcm = require('dpush');
legacyGcm.send(your_GCM_APIKEY, regId, item, function (error, response) {
    if (!error) {
        // success code
    } else {
        // error handling
    }
});
```